# Building a vue3 project SSR. Err on build

Tags: node.js, vuejs3, node-modules, server-side-rendering

I've trying to create SSR VUE3 app. When I trying to build my project, I get an error on build:

```
npm run ssr

> test@0.1.0 pressr
> cross-env SSR=true vue-cli-service build

All browser targets in the browserslist configuration have supported ES module.
Therefore we don't build two separate bundles for differential loading.


 ERROR  Error: Build failed with errors.
Error: Build failed with errors.
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\build\index.js:207:23
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:148:8
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:68:3
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1) 
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Cache.shutdown (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Cache.js:150:23)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1228:15
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1) 
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compiler.close (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1221:23)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:147:16
    at finalCallback (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:441:32)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:458:13
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at onCompiled (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:456:21)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1199:17
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1) 
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1195:33
    at finalCallback (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:2787:11)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3092:11
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3085:38
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:573:10
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2830:7
    at Object.each (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2857:9)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:403:17
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2830:7
    at Object.each (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2857:9)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:226:15
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:501:18
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at fn (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:486:45)
    at _next4 (eval at create (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:573:10
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2830:7
    at Object.each (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2857:9)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:403:17
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2830:7
    at Object.each (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2857:9)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:226:15
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:501:18
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at C:\Users\alemanthea\Desktop\work\aistmebel-final\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:515:46
```

There is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "pressr": "cross-env SSR=true vue-cli-service build",
    "ssr": "node src/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/server-renderer": "^3.0.0-rc.5",
    "@vueform/slider": "^2.1.7",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "qs": "^6.11.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-axios": "^3.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
    "vue3-carousel": "^0.2.11",
    "vue3-markdown-it": "^1.0.10",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-nano": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-bootstrap-vue": "~0.8.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-nano": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

And `vue.config.json`

```
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require("webpack-manifest-plugin");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

exports.chainWebpack = webpackConfig => {
  if (!process.env.SSR) {
    // This is required for repl.it to play nicely with the Dev Server
    webpackConfig.devServer.disableHostCheck(true);
    return;
  }

  webpackConfig
    .entry("app")
    .clear()
    .add("./src/main.server.js");

  webpackConfig.target("node");
  webpackConfig.output.libraryTarget("commonjs2");

  webpackConfig
    .plugin("manifest")
    .use(new WebpackManifestPlugin({ fileName: "ssr-manifest.json" }));

  webpackConfig.externals(nodeExternals({ allowlist: /\.(css|vue)$/ }));

  webpackConfig.optimization.splitChunks(false).minimize(false);

  webpackConfig.plugins.delete("hmr");
  webpackConfig.plugins.delete("preload");
  webpackConfig.plugins.delete("prefetch");
  webpackConfig.plugins.delete("progress");
  webpackConfig.plugins.delete("friendly-errors");

  // console.log(webpackConfig.toConfig())
};
```

I'd updated npm, all libriaries and dependices, trying with --force and --varboose, but get the same errors.
Other than that, I've tried to build without ssr, and when I run the application, I get eval-related errors in the console, although I don't have any functions or libraries that use it..